# JS / Flash library for record voice in web

Tags: javascript, flash, voice

I'm looking for complete javascript/flash library for record user voice via flash.
js code must call flash component to record voice and specify callback functions on stop record.

```
function onRecordStop(ByteArray string) {...}
```

flash part of library must record voice without any server side. Only capture voice and create byteArray.
Is there a ready-made solution?